# How to use HttpClient.GetStreamAsync() method?

Tags: c#, stream, httpclient

I am trying to use `HttpClient.GetStreamAsync()` method to download a file. However there is an issue here. `GetStreamAsync()` methods returns readonly stream, so i cannot use `Length` property to declare byte array buffer into which im trying to read bytes.

```
     using (var file = await _httpClient.GetStreamAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false))
     {
         // it fails at file.Length below
         byte[] blob = new byte[file.Length];
         await file.ReadAsync(blob, 0, (int)file.Length).ConfigureAwait(false);         
     }
```

Comment: `i cannot use Length property to declare byte array buffer into which im trying to read bytes`. stream can return bytes... You don't need to declare an array...

Comment: BTW: Seems like you haven't tried `byte[] blob =  await _httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync`.

Answer (score 15):

You can just read it into a `MemoryStream` and get the byte array from there:

```
using (var file = await _httpClient.GetStreamAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false))
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
  await file.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
  return memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: You should probably await file.CopyToAsync here

Comment: How can you use some sort of progress reporting with this approach?

Comment: @Marcel: I don't believe it's built-in to `CopyToAsync`; you'd have to write your own copy method.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to propose a variation of Stephen's answer that might be a bit simpler/cleaner:

```cs
using var httpResponse = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
return await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This also has the added benefit that `GetAsync` accepts a cancellation token for graceful cancellation scenarios, while `GetStreamAsync` does not, and it also allows you to inspect the status code of the request if you want.

Comment: Sometimes your stream is too large to fit in memory so its preferable to work with a stream as opposed to the whole set of bytes in memory.