# Windows Forms: XML from website to dataGridView

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

I would like to import a specific part of [this](https://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/current/metars.cache.xml) XML **directly** into my dataGridView in Windows Forms, **without** downloading the XML file.

Current working code, which is downloading the complete file (not wanted):

```
var wd = new WebClient();
wd.DownloadFile("https://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/current/metars.cache.xml", @"c:\temp\metars.xml");

var ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(@"c:\temp\metars.xml");

dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["METAR"];
```

Is there a way to get a part of XML, for example METAR information when station_id=CYDL, to dataGridView directly from the link?

Comment: What's wrong with using a temporary file?

Comment: @UweKeim The goal is not to create any extra files on the drive, even if it could be deleted. Organization preference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the content through a stream rather than saving to a file like so:

```
using var client = new HttpClient();
using var contentStream = await client.GetStreamAsync("https://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/current/metars.cache.xml");

var ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(contentStream);

dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["METAR"];
```

Or if you prefer the non-asynchronous (`await`) way:

```
using var client = new HttpClient();
var streamTask = client.GetStreamAsync("https://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/current/metars.cache.xml");
streamTask.Wait();
using var contentStream = streamTask.Result;

var ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(contentStream);

dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["METAR"];
```

Comment: Do you have to [dispose the returned stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41215111/107625) from `GetStreamAsync`?

Comment: @UweKeim I think `HttpClient` will do that when it's disposed itself, so if you're not disposing `HttpClient` you probably should do it explicitly. For good measure I've updated the answer to do so, but it depends on how you use it I believe.

Comment: @OttoTuhkunen Good to hear it. Remember to accept the answer if your question has been answered.